# await does not resume on original context

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

`await` for some reason does not seem to resume on the calling context. I'm calling an `async` method (actually a hierarchy of several `async` methods). Things go fine till I finally reaches the DataService which uses RestSharp's `ExecuteAsync()`. That final call looks like this:

```
IRestResponse Response = await rc.ExecuteAsync(request); //rc is a RestClient object
```

I have debugged it thoroughly and at each level, the following line returns `true`, even just before calling `ExecuteAsync`:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread == System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Thread
```

Only after the `ExecuteAsync()` returns with server data, the above line becomes `false`, indicating that the above `await` did not resume on the calling thread. Thereupon, the higher layers that called this async operation and now want to assign returned data to the UI throw the infamous STA thread exception.

What am I doing wrong? I have burnt several hours already and gone through several SO posts and web articles, but this doesn't seem to work. I have also added `ConfigureAwait(true)` to explicitly ask it to resume on calling context, but it didn't.

This is a VSTO Word add-in. I'm using it with WPF.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This is a VSTO Word add-in.

This is actually the source of the problem.

The actual "context" captured by the `await` is `SynchronizationContext.Current` (unless it is `null`, in which case it is `TaskScheduler.Current`). UI apps like WinForms and WPF provide their own `SynchronizationContext`, which is how `await` resumes on the UI thread.

Except Office add-ins. I'm not sure why, but they do not provide a `SynchronizationContext`. So if you want to use `await` in an Office add-in, you'll need to supply the `SynchronizationContext`.

I believe a WPF-based Office add-in would be able to do this at the beginning of every `async` event:

```
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new DispatcherSynchronizationContext());
```

But I have never actually tried this. :)

Comment: Two related questions: 1. Is it required to set synchronization context before every awaitable, or can I do it once upon startup of my add-in? 2. Can I somehow get WPF's built-in/default synchronization context, or do I have to do it like `new DispatcherSynchronizationContext()`? (I looked into the libs and the closest thing I got was `System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher`, but it doesn't give me access to the context object).

Comment: 1. I *think* you could do it just once, but you'd need to test that out to be sure.
2. I don't know of a way to do that. But I wouldn't worry about it; last time I checked, WPF itself would use multiple SyncCtx instances that all referred to the same dispatcher (one per top-level window IIRC).

Comment: Here after a year. Just in case it helps someone, I have confirmed that you need to set synchronization context before every async operation; so setting it up once in the startup is not enough. But you can create one global object (e.g. an `internal` variable in your `ThisAddIn` class) that you can then pass every time you call `SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext` function.