# await does not resume on main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, vsto

### Background

I faced this problem a couple of years ago and got [this very helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65307292/await-does-not-resume-on-original-context) from Stephen Cleary. Problem with VSTO add-ins is that they do not set a `SynchronizationContext` and therefore async calls do not resume on UI thread, causing all sorts of cross-thread access troubles. The solution, as he mentioned is to manually call `SetSynchronizationContext` before calling any `async` function.

I have been using this technique since then and thought that was all there was to it. But today I have seen a situation where even manually setting the context does not force it to resume on calling thread.

### Situation

My VSTO add-in contains a WPF pane (inside a CustomTaskPane) which is bound to its ViewModel that contains several `AsyncRelayCommand` properties (from WCT). One of these commands calls my Data Service which in turn calls a RestSharp methods to fetch data from the API server.

All these calls use `async`/`await` and all these call use `ConfigureAwait(false)` except the one at the top level (i.e. the command itself). Here is a snapshot of how this call-site looks like:

[image]

As you can see, I have manually called `SetSynchronizationContext` before doing the `await` call. It also shows that `SynchronizationContext.Current` is set after it resumes after the await call, but somehow the code is still running on the worker thread. I also verified that the code was running on UI thread when it hit line 259 before drilling down into the `await` call.

I have already spent a lot of time and effort on this and can't make any sense of it. Can anyone help me figure out if I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: Where do you get a synchronization context for setting it up?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev: I do it early in the life of my add-in. There is a `SyncContext = new DispatcherSynchronizationContext();` line in the Startup event. This object is then passed to all VMs through IoC/DI.

Comment: Try using the `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` class instead.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev: I'll try that. However, my entire UI is in WPF (except for CustomTaskPane itself, of course).

Comment: Also you may consider using the Tasks instead where you could specify a synchronization context under which you would like to continue, see [Specifying a synchronization context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=net-7.0#specifying-a-synchronization-context) for more information.

Comment: That seems to have worked. Don't know why. But thanks a lot. I had spent way too much time on it. If you know the difference between the two SynchronizationContext implementations and why `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` should be used here, please post it and I'll happily accept it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an instance of the [WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) class instead.

The `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` class provides a synchronization mechanism for Windows Forms.

The `DispatcherSynchronizationContext` class is for WPF applications which uses two threads. One thread is background thread for rendering and the other thread is for UI. So, UI elements in one thread are not accessible to other UI threads. Microsoft introduced the dispatcher which is responsible for multiple UI threads interaction.

Comment: Thanks. That fixes the problem at hand. I'm accepting it as answer. Though I'm still interested in knowing the difference between the two. If you or anyone else who lands here know why `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` is more appropriate than `DispatcherSynchronizationContext` in a VSTO add-in, plz share your knowledge here.

Comment: I've updated the post with a difference between the two.